# How to organize a Main controller for all the child controllers in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to make something like this:

```
Main_Controller -> {


   child1_controller

   child2_controller

   child3_controller


}
```

the purpose is to execute the constructor of the Main class everytime the child classes have been executed, it looks like some kind of multi extending, for example if i want to check in the main constructor wheter is admin or not, but the problem is when i do that

```
child1_controller extends Main_Controller
```

i get an error Class 'Main_Controller' not found

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the built in [core class extending mechanism](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/core_classes.html), if you name your base controller class appropriately (with the default prefix `MY_`) and put it under `application/core` CI should pick it up.

Once you got your `MY_Controller` set up, you can make your child controllers under `application/controllers/` extend that, and call for `parent::__construct()` in their `__construct`.

Comment: You should choose this answer as the solution if it worked for you. :)